# How to convert an Object to enum to use it in a switch statment

Tags: java, enums

Using Java 8, I have a Map that I need to convert to another Map replacing the key names and sometimes the value. E.g., when they turn out to be enums in which case I need to convert these enums to other constants (Strings and sometimes ints). I do not want to compare Strings, i.e. `theEnum.name()`, due to possible duplicates but would prefer to convert the Object to an enum and switch on it. However, I fail to find a way to convert the Object to a switchable enum. `Enum.valueOf` does not return something that can be switched upon (see the example below).

```
private void put(String key, Object value) {
  if (value != null && value.getClass().isEnum()) {
  Enum<?> val = (Enum<?>)value; 
  /* The below line has the following problem:
   * Cannot switch on a value of type Enum. 
   * Only convertible int values, strings or enum variables are 
   * permitted */
  switch (Enum.valueOf(val.getClass(), val.name())) {
    case EmploymentType.FULL_TIME_EMPLOYEE : value = "Fast anställd";
         break;
    case ResidenceType.TENANCY : value = "Hyresrätt";
         break;
    default : break;
  }
}
map.put(key, value);
```

}

I am aware that I could do:

```
private void put(String key, Object value) {
  if (value != null && value.getClass().isEnum()) {
    if (value.equals(EmploymentType.FULL_TIME_EMPLOYEE) value = "Fast anställd";
    else if (value.equals(ResidenceType.TENANCY) value = "Hyresrätt";
  }
  map.put(key, value);    
}
```

But is find that to be much less elegant and as easy to read as a switch statement would be. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have to deal with multiple enum types. But you can't switch accross multiple enum types in one switch statement. I think you could just use a `Map<Enum<?>, Object>` instead.

You could setup an `HashMap` like this:

```
Map<Enum<?>, Object> enumMap = new HashMap<>();
enumMap.put(EmploymentType.FULL_TIME_EMPLOYEE, "Fast anställd");
enumMap.put(ResidenceType.TENANCY, "Hyresrätt");
```

and use it like this:

```
if (enumMap.containsKey(value)) {
    value = enumMap.get(value);
}
map.put(key, value);
```

Comment: Or just `if(enumMap.containsKey(value))`.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, this is better since then it behaves like OPs version if there is no value defined for a given enum - edited it.

Comment: That would have been nice but unfortunately only SOME of the keys in the map are enums so cannot restrict the keys to that. However, I could use the approach to iterate through the original and build another Map with only enums.

Comment: @Per The `enumMap` in my example replaces the switch/if-else statement not your destination or source map. It is a transformation of the code inside of your `if (value != null && value.getClass().isEnum()) {}` block.

Comment: Yes, i realized that when trying it out. It is a very good solution, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to have the enums implement an interface with a `getValue()` or similar method. Even if it were possible to switch between different enums, that code isn't very elegant.

Then you could just write

```
if (value != null && value instanceof MyInterface) {
    MyInterface foo = (MyInterface) value;
    value = foo.getValue();   // Although it's a bit ugly to reassign a parameter
}
map.put(key, value);
```

Comment: `value != null` is redundant, since null always fails an instanceof test.

Comment: I just wrote a tiny program to verify that it does not. Also, the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) states “At run time, the result of the instanceof operator is true if the value of the RelationalExpression is not null and the reference could be cast to the ReferenceType without raising a ClassCastException. Otherwise the result is false.”

Comment: @VGR Ah you're right, my mind was on overloaded method invocation where a null parameter acts...interestingly.

Answer (score 0):

Both Calculatos and Kaymans answers are good solutions. After trying them out i choose to go with Calculators as it is less intrusive and use the approach suggested to build another Map with only enums in the constructor and then use that enum map to convert the enums in the put method exactly as suggested i.e.

```
if (enumMap.containsKey(value)) {
  value = enumMap.get(value);
}
map.put(key, value);
```